# Is it possible to edit a previously sent chat message using the Skype4Py api?

Tags: python, skype4py

As the title says, I'm curious if the functionality of editing a sent chat message can be replicated programatically using the Skype4Py api. I'm not sure when Skype added this feature, and the API, as far as I know, hasn't been maintained in some years, so I was just curious.

I don't see anything that looks like it would do it in the docs, but,I figured I check here before I give up.

Comment: @Joran Beasley -- Right click on the message ;) Edit is an option in the context menu, or you can press the `up` arrow key after typing a message and it allows you to edit the most recent. There's mention in the docs of checking if something *is* editable.. but no mention of *how* to edit it.

Comment: If the Skype API protocol call is not implemented patches welcome :) https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, each chat message has a body (the text of the message) and a IsEditable property. So long as IsEditable=True you should be able to do m.Body = "some new text"